# Spring 3 MVC: how to create the form-backing object at form submission?

Tags: forms, spring, model-view-controller, object, backing

I read a few tutorials about forms and submission in Spring 3 MVC. All these examples store the form backing object in the session the following way:

```
@SessionAttributes({"command"})
```

What I would like to do is to create the form object (for example: load it from the database) at the moment of form submission, not storing it in the session to be used at the moment of form submission.

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you please provide a link to any of that turorials. It sounds strange that ALL store the form backing object in a SESSION. -- I asked for the link, because I have the feeling that you anderstand anyting wrong.

Comment: Have you read the [reference guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods)?

Answer (score 2):

Normally in Spring 3 you have only this line for form binding:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/addContact", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("contact")
                        Contact contact, BindingResult result) {
```

*(you can even skip the `@ModelAttribute("contact")` annotation)*

There is no session.

May have a look at this tutorial: [Spring 3 MVC: Handling Forms in Spring 3.0 MVC](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/07/spring-3-mvc-handling-forms.html)

*But I already have requested you to post a link to the tutorial you used. -- Maybe we are talking about different things.*